# Marshal.SizeOf throws ArgumentException on enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums, marshalling

Consider this code:

```
public enum MyEnum { V1, V2, V3 }

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyEnum));
```

it throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   TestConsole.exe
>
> Additional information: Type 'TestConsole.Program+MyEnum' cannot be
>   marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can
>   be computed.

While this code doesn't throw an exception and `size` contains 4:

```
public enum MyEnum { V1, V2, V3 }

public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyEnum en;
}

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
```

Can anyone explain why the .NET framework can't figure out that the `enum` is 4 bytes in the first sample code?

**UPDATE**

`Marshal.Sizeof()` failed on me in this generic method:

```
public bool IoControlReadExact<T>(uint ioControlCode, out T output) where T : struct
{
    output = new T();

    int outBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    IntPtr outBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(outBufferSize);
    if (outBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
        return false;
    try
    {
        uint bytesReturned;
        return IoControlRead(ioControlCode, outBuffer, (uint)outBufferSize, out bytesReturned) && ((uint)outBufferSize == bytesReturned);
    }
    finally
    {
        output = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(outBuffer, typeof(T));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outBuffer);
    }
}
```

And the compiler didn't complain about `enum` not being a `struct`.

**SOLUTION**

I could refactor my generic method to make it work for both `struct` and `enum`:

```
// determine the correct output type:
Type outputType = typeof(T).IsEnum ? Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) : typeof(T);
//...
int outBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(outputType);
//...
output = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(outBuffer, outputType);
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219413/c-sharp-sizeofenum-alternative-to-workaround-resharper-false-error) doesn't explain why, but gives a workaround.

Comment: In contrast, it _is_ possible to create a pointer type to `MyEnum`, with unsafe code, that is use the type `MyEnum*`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation imposed by a difference between the requirements of ECMA-335 for enums (ECMA-335 Partition II §14.3):

> ...they shall have auto field layout (§10.1.2); ...

And the expectations of `Marshal.SizeOf`:

> You can use this method when you do not have a structure. The layout must be sequential or explicit.

Based on this, you will need to use `Enum.GetUnderlyingType` before calling `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: All enums have auto layout, whether or not you explicitly give the underlying type. It is a property in the underlying bytecode metadata.

Comment: Note that the following code is valid (even outside `unsafe` context) and gives the expected value: `const int s = sizeof(MyEnum);`. So the C# compiler gladly uses the "width" of the underlying integral type, and the expression is considered a compile-time constant.

Comment: Above answer is corroborated by the fact that if we declare a `struct` with a couple of integer fields (say) in it, and decorate the struct with the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]` attribute, then this struct behaves exactly like an enum type wrt. "size of". That is `Marshal.SizeOf` throws same exception, whereas `sizeof(...)` works (but is only allowed in `unsafe` context since this "size" is not considered a compile-time constant).

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf will support enums soon https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/23230#issuecomment-473001308

Answer (score 0):

`Marshal.SizeOf(t)` does want to have a unmanaged struct, and an enum is a managed struct. [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) can figure out the constant size of an enum:

```
int size1 = sizeof(MyEnum);
Console.WriteLine("Enum: {0}", size1);
int size2 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
Console.WriteLine("Struct: {0}", size2);
```

Comment: For the special case of an Enum there may be the [Enum.GetUnderlyingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx) method of interest

Comment: Copy the code from Wouter Huysentruit and read the exception 'Type 'MyEnum' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.'

Comment: Enum is not a struct, just as System.Int32 is not a struct, even though it is declared like that.  Such a declaration is only relevant when the value type value is *boxed*.